# How to join two tables using RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two text files: `color.txt` and `shades.txt`

with following values:

**color.txt**

```
1 | RED 
2 | GREEN
3 | BLUE
```

**shades.txt**

```
1 | 1 | dark red
2 | 1 | light red
3 | 2 | dark green
4 | 3 | light blue
5 | 3 | sky blue
```

How can I join the two tables using RDD. The second column of `shades.txt` is the key from `color.txt`.

**What i've done so far**

```
var colorRdd = sc.textFile("/pathto/color.txt")
var shadesRdd = sc.textFile("/pathto/shaes.txt")

var colorPairRdd = colorRdd.map{ case (colorkey, colorname) => ((colorkey), colorname)}
```

with this I get an error:

```
found   : (T1, T2)
 required: String
```

Comment: make 2 rdds and join them by key. Where did you stuck?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to convert the data into an RDD. Should I create two classes color and shade? Once I have two RDDs should I group them by key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read each file and create RDD

```
rdd= sc.textFile("file.txt")
```

2. Parse string (you should already have `RDD[String]`).

For example map function below returns split each line by separator.

```
rdd.map(x => x.split("\\|"))
```

3. Create `PairRDD`. From array strings build pair:

```
rdd.map(a => (a[0],a[1]))
```

Steps 2 and 3 can be combined and refactored for better code.

4. Join both RDDs

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).map (process here )
```

Comment: I'm getting an error while creating the pairrdd. Please see my updates

Comment: you don't have initially pair when you do map. Map function should be from string to pair

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it for `color` so I can replicate it. Do I need to parse the string and use delimiter `|`? How do I do that?

Comment: @Anthony use `map(x => x.split("\\|"))`